# How can we change the admin form element position in magento?

Tags: magento

[image]

How can we change the position (Sort Order) of admin form element?

Comment: Are you using magento entreprise or a custom module for the customer attributes displayed here?

Comment: How did you add your custom attribute? If you done it via code then you can also add in an order for the field.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:**

You can specify a caret `^` as an optional fourth argument when defining your field:

```
    $fieldset->addField('my_element','text',array(
      'name'  => 'my_element',
      'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('My Element')
    ),'^');
```

---

**More Information**

See `Varien_Data_Form_Abstract::addField`:

```
/**
 * Add child element
 *
 * if $after parameter is false - then element adds to end of collection
 * if $after parameter is null - then element adds to befin of collection
 * if $after parameter is string - then element adds after of the element with some id
 *
 * @param   string $elementId
 * @param   string $type
 * @param   array  $config
 * @param   mixed  $after
 * @return Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
 */
public function addField($elementId, $type, $config, $after=false)
{
    if (isset($this->_types[$type])) {
        $className = $this->_types[$type];
    }
    else {
        $className = 'Varien_Data_Form_Element_'.ucfirst(strtolower($type));
    }
    $element = new $className($config);
    $element->setId($elementId);
    if ($element->getRequired()) {
        $element->addClass('required-entry');
    }
    $this->addElement($element, $after);
    return $element;
}
```

The comments tell you how to order your elements. So, to position your field, specify a fourth argument `$after` of `somefield` or whatever is the ID of the field you wish to place yours after.

This is useful when you are extending the customer account form within your own class. Here's an example that places a new form element above the first in the form:

```
class Yourcompany_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account {

  ...

  public function initForm() {
    parent::initForm();

    $form=$this->getForm();

    $fieldset=$form->getElement('base_fieldset');

    $fieldset->addField('my_element','text',array(
      'name'  => 'my_element',
      'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('My Element')
    ),'^');

    return $this;
  }

  ...

}
```

You may notice something strange. My fourth argument to the `addField` call is a caret (`'^'`). This places the element at the very top of the form, which is what you appear to be asking in your question.

But wait! Why doesn't this match up to the code documentation shown above?! Well, it looks like a disconnect in consistent coding convention during development. If you follow the code, you will find that `addField` makes it way to the `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Collection::add` method. It is in here that we see a 2nd argument, `$after`, which notes in the comments:

```
/**
 * Add element to collection
 *
 * @todo get it straight with $after
 * @param Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
 * @param boolean|'^'|string $after
 * @return Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
 */
public function add(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element, $after=false)
```

Here we find that `false` appends the element to the fieldset, a `^` character prepends the element, and passing in an element ID will place the element after the one specified.

---

**UPDATE: How to Deal With Existing Fields**

What if you want to re-order an existing field? Unfortunately, ordering takes places at the time of adding the field, and cannot conveniently be changed after that. But I can offer 2 approaches to get the job done.

**Method 1: Re-Order by Removing and Adding Again**

```
$fieldset->removeField('core_element');
$fieldset->addField('core_element','text',array(
  'name'  => 'core_element',
  'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Core Element')
),'^');
```

This is a simple solution, but requires you to manually re-define that field. In some cases this will be easy enough. In others, not so. For those scenarios, see next.

**Method 2: Re-Order by Cloning**

```
$element=clone $form->getElement('core_element');
$fieldset->removeField('core_element');
$fieldset->addElement($element,'^');
```

I think this is the best solution, because it preserves the element definition as it was originally written. This is especially important in the case of attributes whose fields are generated in part by their `frontend_input_renderer` classes. Learn more about that [here](http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-eav-system/#frontend_model).

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'attribute_id' & 'sort_order' fields in 'customer_eav_attribute' table.